# Polynomial equations using letters

Tags: javascript, php, algebra

I am building a script that calculates the genetics of animals that are bred together. Each animal has a set of genes (e.g. BbEeKk) and the program should calculate all the genetic possibilities of the offspring. But I am not sure how to do equations on letters, as the entire solution would be dealing with multiplying polynomials using just letters. So far, the script is in PHP. But if PHP cannot handle this type of equation, it can be easily shifted to a different one.

Here is an example of how (on paper) you would find the offspring of a cross between BbEEKk and bbeeKk:

```
// First we take the individual gene pairs and multiply them together
(B + b)(b + b) = 2Bb + 2bb
(E + E)(e + e) = 4Ee
(K + k)(K + k) = 1KK + 2Kk + 1kk

// Take those and form a polynomial
(2Bb + 2bb)(4Ee)(1KK + 2Kk + 1kk)

// Multiply first two expressions
(6BbEe + 6bbEe)(1KK + 2Kk + 1kk)

// Multiply remaining two expressions
(6BbEeKK + 12BbEeKk + 6BbEekk + 6bbEeKK + 12bbEeKk + 6bbEekk)
```

Extracting those final values we get:

```
12/64 (18.75%) offspring as BbEeKk
12/64 (18.75%) offspring as bbEeKk 
6/64 (9.375%) offspring as BbEeKK
6/64 (9.375%) offspring as BbEekk
6/64 (9.375%) offspring as bbEeKK
6/64 (9.375%) offspring as bbEekk
```

I simply can't seem to find a way for PHP to handle this kind of operation, and I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript to know if it can either.

Comment: that's an interesting one. My girlfriend will kill me (she's a biologist) but can you please elabrorate further how those number-character combinations are formed?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by formed, but the character combinations are just representative of the different genes. So each parent has a set of 3 genes (B, E, and K) and since they can combine in a number of different way each number represents a repeated genepair so to speak.

If you have ever done punnett chart, this is attempting to be mathmatical representation of one. http://scienceprimer.com/punnett-square-calculator

Comment: May I suggest you to post this on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ I think there are better languages than php and javascript to solve this in an efficient way

Comment: Will do, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I have a question: (2Bb + 2bb)(4Ee) = (6BbEe + 6bbEe) ? It's late. but is this correct? not (8BbEe + 8bbEe)?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting :)

Lets integrate Maths with programming.

First of all, I think you made a mistake in example, it should be

```
// First we take the individual gene pairs and multiply them together
(B + b)(b + b) = 2Bb + 2bb
(E + E)(e + e) = 4Ee
(K + k)(K + k) = 1KK + 2Kk + 1kk

// Take those and form a polynomial
(2Bb + 2bb)(4Ee)(1KK + 2Kk + 1kk)

// Multiply first two expressions
(8BbEe + 8bbEe)(1KK + 2Kk + 1kk)

// Multiply remaining two expressions
(8BbEeKK + 16BbEeKk + 8BbEekk + 8bbEeKK + 16bbEeKk + 8bbEekk)
```

This way, sum of all possible spring is 100%

This can easily be solved by applying Matrix calculations,

The first step would be to consider genes as numbers

```
bb ==> 0
bB ==> Bb ==> 1
BB ==> 2
```

Same for any letters.

Once you have following equation:

```
(2Bb + 2bb)(4Ee)(1KK + 2Kk + 1kk)
```

you can translate it to matrix operation:

```
[2 2 0] * [0 4 0] * [1 2 1]
```

Consider taking transpose of matrix for dimension matching. The resultant matrix will give you the numbers whose sum would be 64.

Comment: Good catch! That's what I get for doing it too quickly to get it up here. hehe. I never thought about using a matrix operation either! Would it be easy to break back down into a string format for display?

Comment: Yes, You will get result for all possible combinations, the number in resultant matrix will belong to a particular Gene set depending upon how (sequence) you are multiplying. Try in Matlab, will take hardly couple of minutes if you know Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand this correctly, then first we have to seperate "BbEEKk" into 
"Bb", "EE", Kk", and the same with "bbeeKk". 
Afterwards, we should have "Bb" and "bb". 
I fiddled a little with this and I think I solved the first part with multiplying them together, if you separate them like I wrote:

```
function test($a,$b){
if ($a[0] == $a[1]) {

    if ($b[0] == $b[1]) {
        return "4" . $a[0] . $b[0];
    }
    return "2" . $b[0] . $a[0] . "+2" . $a[0] . $a[0];
} elseif ($b[0] == $b[1]) {

    if ($a[0] == $a[1]) {
        return "4" . $b[0] . $a[0];
    }
    return "2" . $a[0] . $b[0] . "+2" . $b[0] . $b[0];
} elseif ($a[0] != $a[1]) {
    return "1" . $a[0] . $a[0] . "+2" . $a . "+1" . $a[1] . $a[1];
}
}
```

It should be possible to do the same as I did here with the other steps.

Comment: While I like your answer, that's the reason I asked the OP to ask this question on code golf. With php, there's too much replacing and code rewriting. I think a language like J could solve this better, but php isn't the right for it. This would become a massive mess til the end.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you there, was just merely showing OP that it can be done, but the part I made was just the simple part of the 3 steps he makes, and even that code looks messy. Would also recommend OP to use another language for this.

Comment: Thank you for this example. I will look at other languages to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

one solution (it's a "brute force" solution and not rly pretty):

```
<?php
    $seqs = ["BbEEKk", "bbeeKk"];
    // chunk them to parts of 2 chars
    $seqs = array_map(function($el) {return str_split($el,2);}, $seqs);
    echo "<pre>".print_r($seqs,true)."</pre>";
    // cross the two sequence strings:
    $step1 = [];
    for($i=0;$i<count($seqs[0]);$i++)
        $step1[] = multiplySequences([$seqs[0][$i], $seqs[1][$i]]);
    echo "<pre>".print_r($step1,true)."</pre>";
    // now multiply the result and sort them:
    $step2 = multiplySequences($step1);
    usort($step2, function($a, $b) {
        return $b[0]-$a[0];
    });
    echo "<pre>".print_r($step2,true)."</pre>";

    // takes an array of sequenzes. a sequenze is an array of sequenzeparts. a sequenzepart is an array [0=>number, 1=>the sequenz as chars]
    function multiplySequences($seqs) {
        foreach($seqs as &$seq)
            multiplySequencesPrepare($seq);
        // multiply them all:
        $t = $seqs[0];
        for($i=1;$i<count($seqs);$i++) {
            $t = multiplySequencesHelper($t, $seqs[$i]);
            $t = multiplySequencesPrepare($t);
        }
        return $t;
    }
    // prepare the data to process them. it defines the format from above: input can be a string "2Bb" or an array. if it's an array there are to possibilities: 1) [0=>number, 1=>sequence] or [[0=>number, 1=>sequence],[0=>number, 1=>sequence],...]
    function multiplySequencesPrepare(&$seq) {
        if(is_array($seq))
            $seq = array_map(function($s) { if(is_array($s)) return $s; preg_match('/(\d*)(\w+)/', $s, $s); $s[1]=(int)$s[1]==0?1:(int)$s[1]; return array_slice($s,1);}, $seq);
        else
            $seq = call_user_func(function($s) {
                preg_match('/(\d*)(\w+)/', $s, $s);
                $s[2] = str_split($s[2]);
                $s[1]=(int)$s[1]==0?1:(int)$s[1];
                return array_map(function($sp) use($s) { return [$s[1], $sp]; }, $s[2]);
            }, $seq);
        return $seq;
    }
    // calculate the result of two sequences:
    function multiplySequencesHelper($seq1, $seq2) {
        $res = [];
        $cnt = [];
        foreach($seq1 as $s1)
            foreach($seq2 as $s2) {
                $c1 = $s1[1];
                $c2 = $s2[1];
                $res[] = $tcc = ($c1<$c2?$c1.$c2:$c2.$c1);
                $cnt[$tcc] = $s1[0]*$s2[0];
            }
        $tmp = array_count_values($res);
        return array_map(function($el) use($tmp,$cnt) { return ($cnt[$el]*$tmp[$el]).$el; }, array_unique($res));   
    }
```

**tested** comments inside the code should explain it.